# Is there any particular way to approach "finding an example" questions in elementary set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, problem-solving

How should one approach answering questions like:

"Find an example of sets [a different number of sets] such that [some statement involving those sets]."

Guess and trial based on your intuition of the whole statement is the only way? If so, what about more complex statements?

So I'll give you an example: Find an example of sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $(A ∪ B) △ C \neq (A △ C) ∪ (B △ C)$.

What's your way of solving this problem (except for guessing, if there's any that I'm missing)?

**One short note:** If you're considering that my question is too general then please only answer the example above and the way that you approached to solve it (if possible).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try proving said statement. You'll get stuck eventually if it's false. Then try to find an example for the part of your "proof" that breaks down. Typically this example will apply to the problem as a whole.

Comment: what John said, where "said statement" is the claim that there are no examples of such sets.

Comment: A venn diagram would probably tell you immediately why those two are different. Then you need to construct an example where the "difference" is non-empty, which should be easy, just assign one element to each region.

Comment: What is that triangle shape ??

Comment: That is the symbol for the symmetric difference.

Comment: you can break some things down into parts. for you example i think it would take c being the union of a and b for example. edit: okay I did this example thinking it was the set theoretic difference.

Comment: @Heptapod that's the XOR right ? Like if $u\in A "triangle" B$ then $u\in A-B \text{ or } u\in B-A$

Comment: @Furrane they said 3 minutes ago it was the symmetric difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Guess and trial based on your intuition of the whole statement is the only way?

It's not the **only** way, but it's the way you **should** approach such problems.

The *point* of posing such problems as exercises is not that students should train some kind of mechanical procedure for finding examples -- that would be a mostly useless skill.

On the other hand, developing enough **intuition** about how sets and logic work *is* a useful skill, and doing so is what such exercises is meant to give you an opportunity for.

Do not squander this opportunity by trying to find a mindless way of solving them instead of developing the intuition that is the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Following the idea of John Griffin in comments, let us try to "prove" that $(A ∪ B) △ C = (A △ C) ∪ (B △ C)$. At a certain point we will get stuck and the part of our "proof" that breaks down will suggest us a counterexample. We should prove that $(A ∪ B) △ C \subseteq (A △ C) ∪ (B △ C)$ and $(A ∪ B) △ C \supseteq (A △ C) ∪ (B △ C)$.

- "Proof" of $(A ∪ B) △ C \supseteq (A △ C) ∪ (B △ C)$: Let $x \in (A △ C) ∪ (B △ C)$. Either $x \in A △ C$ or $x \in  B △ C$, suppose $x \in A △ C$. There are two cases:

  1. if $x \in A \smallsetminus C$, then $x \in A \subseteq A \cup B$ and $x \notin C$, thus $x \in (A \cup B) △ C$;
  2. if $x \in C \smallsetminus A$, then $x \in C$ and $x \notin A$. Now, either $x \in B$ or $x \notin B$ (*tertium non datur*) and both are possible since we haven't supposed anything about the relationship between $x$ and $B$ (i.e. $B$ plays no role in this case). If $x \notin B$ then $x \notin A \cup B$ and hence $x \in (A \cup B) △ C$. But if $x \in B$ then $x \in A \cup B$ and so $x \notin (A \cup B) △ C$. We got stuck! We can't prove that $(A ∪ B) △ C \supseteq (A △ C) ∪ (B △ C)$.

Summing up, trying to "prove" that $(A ∪ B) △ C \supseteq (A △ C) ∪ (B △ C)$, we've found that the statement is false when there is an $x \in  B \cup C$ such that $x \notin A$. This suggests an example of sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $(A∪B)△C≠(A△C)∪(B△C)$: take $B = \{1\} = C$ and $A = \emptyset$, so that $1 \in B \cup C$ and $1 \notin A$; then, $A △ C = \{1\} = A \cup B$ while $B △ C = \emptyset $, therefore $(A \cup B) △ C = \emptyset \neq \{1\} = (A △ C) \cup (B △ C)$.